# Making a Given String a Palindrome

Tags: java, oop, recursion, palindrome

Can someone please discuss and explain a way I can modify my code to function with these test cases... I am trying to make my program take a word and make it a palindrome by replacing one letter in a word that prevents the word from being a palindrome

Desired test cases:

```
Palindromes.isPalindrome2("cat", 'c') => true
Palindromes.isPalindrome2("axaa", 'x') => true
Palindromes.isPalindrome2("12bb", 'b') => true
Palindromes.isPalindrome2("ca", 'c') => true
```

This is what I have thus far...

```
public class Palindromes {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        //Strip out non-alphanumeric characters from string
        String cleanWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
        //Check for palindrome quality recursively
        return checkPalindrome(cleanWord);
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome2(String word) {
        //Strip out non-alphanumeric characters from string
        String cleanWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
        //Check for palindrome quality recursively
        return checkPalindrome2(cleanWord);
    }

    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String word) {
        if(word.length() < 2) { 
            return true;  
        }
        char first  = word.charAt(0);
        char last   = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
        if(first != last) { 
            return false; 
        }
        else { 
            return checkPalindrome(word.substring(1,word.length()-1));
        }
    }

    public void replace(int first, int last) {
        if(first != last)
        { first = last;}
        else if(last != first) 
        { last = first;}
        }

    public static boolean checkPalindrome2(String word) {
        char special = 0;
        if(word.length() < 2) { 
            return true;  
        }
        char first  = word.charAt(0);
        char last   = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
        if(first != last) { 
            return false; 
        }
        if(first != last)
            return false; 
        else {
            return checkPalindrome2(word.substring(1,word.length()-1));
        }
    }
}
```

replace() was my attempt at handling the wildcard letter, but I cant seem to find the appropriate solution... All help will be greatly appreciated. thanks...

Comment: this smells like homework.  In any event... wouldn't this case 'Palindromes.isPalindrome2("12bb", 'b')' be false? Or am I overlooking a replacement here that has this reading backwards and forwards the same way?

Comment: program should replace 1 and 2 with b and b

Comment: Well for one, your `replace` method modifies the local variables.  You need a better way of setting the variables, an easy solution would be returning a `Pair<Integer, Integer>` object

Comment: oh, so it should hunt after all possible replacements? Well... the strong arm way to do this is to take turns replacing every single character with your replacement char and seeing if the resulting string is a palendrome. Are you hoping for something more elegant and less processor intensive?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, I think the more elegant solution would involve dynamic programming.

Comment: @justderb... umm ok good luck with that :)

Comment: wait... I just realized that if it's hunting for ALL possible replacements, then you'll ALWAYS succeed by simply replacing every single character in the string with your replacement character! I suspect you're misunderstanding your assignment.  More likely you should be looking to replace all instances of a specific character, or just one instance of it. And again, 'Palindromes.isPalindrome2("12bb", 'b')' should return false.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I think it probably wants the solution as the least amount of characters changed to make a palindrome... but yes, that is a "solution" :P

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I have a restriction to one letter. So i say the String is aabbcc it will be false. But if it were aabb it would be true because one letter only is needed to create the palindrome

Comment: Your logic doesn't follow with the example of Palindromes.isPalindrome2("12bb", 'b')... what's your one letter there? Or are you simply stripping out the numbers before you get started and not doing any replacement at all (leaving bb intact)?

Comment: I see... ok, sorry, I wasn't following along.  Ok, well... then it's really straight forward, just walk through your word taking one char at a time, regEx replacing all instances of it with your substitution and seeing if the resulting String is equal to itself backwards. Do it a second time just replacing one letter at a time, in case the global replace actually hurts you rather than helps.

Comment: @choloboy7 what single letter would you replace to turn aabb into a palindrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my steps I would do:

- Split the received string into 2 substrings.  The first string `front` being the front half of the string, the second string `back` being the half end of the string.

Example:

```java
char replacement = 'c';

String input = "aabbcc";
StringBuilder front = new StringBuilder(input.substring(0, input.length()/2));
// Do modulus to not include the odd middle (it mirrors itself)
StringBuilder back = new StringBuilder(input.substring((input.length()/2)+(input.length()%2));
```

- Compare the two strings, replacing if one matches but the other doesn't.  If neither match each other and is not the given 'replacement' character, return false.  If you do more than one replacement, return false (since that is what you said the requirement is)

Example:

```java
int replacements = 0;
for (int i=0; i < front.length(); ++i)
{
    int backIndex = back.length() - i;
    if (front.charAt(i) != back.charAt(backIndex))
    {
        // Characters do not match at all to given replacement
        if ((front.charAt(i) != replacement) &&
            (back.charAt(backIndex) != replacement)
        {
            // Cannot make it 
            // (Or if you want to force it, set both to replacement
            //  by deleting this one if statement)
            return false;
        }
        // Front matches replacement
        else if (front.charAt(i) == replacement)
        {
            // Replace back character with replacement
            back.setCharAt(backIndex, replacement);
            replacements++;
        }
        // Back matches replacement
        else if (back.charAt(backIndex) == replacement)
        {
            // Replace front character with replacement
            front.setCharAt(i, replacement);
            replacements++;
        }
        if (replacements > 1)
        {
            // Can only replace one
            return false;
        }
    }
}

String output = front.toString() + back.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code, it splits the input into two halves, and compares the first half to the reversed second half. If they are equal, the input is already a palindrome. If they are not equal, it iterates through the first half, exchanging letters with the input `char` to replace with, and comparing with the reversed second half at every step. Then it does the same thing, but using the second half instead of the first half:

```
public class CanMakePalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("cat using c: " + canMakePalindrome("cat", 'c'));
        System.out.println("axaa using x: " + canMakePalindrome("axaa", 'x'));
        System.out.println("12bb using b: " + canMakePalindrome("12bb", 'b'));
        System.out.println("ca using c: " + canMakePalindrome("ca", 'c'));
    }

    private static boolean canMakePalindrome(String input, char c) {
        int length = input.length();
        String start = input.substring(0, length/2);
        String end = input.substring(length/2+length%2, length); // need modulus in the case of odd length input

        return (replaceLoop(start,end, c) || replaceLoop(end,start, c));
    }

    private static boolean replaceLoop(String start, String end, char c) {
        if (start.equals(reverse(end))) {
            System.out.println("Input is already a palindrome.");
            return true;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<start.length(); i++) {
            char[] startchars = start.toCharArray();
            char[] endchars = end.toCharArray();
            endchars = reverse(endchars);
            startchars[i] = c;
            if ((new String(startchars).equals(new String(endchars)))) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static char[] reverse(char[] input) {
        int length = input.length;
        char[] reversed = new char[length];
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            reversed[length-i-1]=input[i];
        }
        return reversed;
    }

    private static String reverse(String input){
        String reversed = new String(reverse(input.toCharArray())); 
        return reversed;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
cat using c: true
axaa using x: true
12bb using b: false
ca using c: true
```

Note that 12bb cannot be made into a palindrome using only one character change, so your test case appears to not match your specifications of replacing only one letter. Also my code will return true if given an empty string as input.